# Does $A\geq B$ imply $(C+A)^{-1}A\geq (C+B)^{-1}B$ for square positive definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Consider three symmetric, square, positive definite matrices (A, B, C), such that $$A\geq B.$$ (The positive semidefinite partial order is assumed) Can we conclude that $$(C+A)^{-1}*A\geq (C+B)^{-1}*B?$$ In the reals this is obvious, but I'm not sure if it extends to matrices.

Comment: did you try for random examples?, not that it is conclusive, but it might be a interesting first step.

Comment: I haven't tried, actually. That is a good Idea.

Comment: Usually, $C\le D$ is taken to mean that $C, D$ are self-adjoint and $D-C$ is positive definite. The matrices in your second inequality need not be self-adjoint, however.

Comment: Thank you, this is true, I think that I do not have guaranteed the order of the objects in the second inequality, and these real matrices might not even be symmetric. I think I'll just have to deal with it.